# Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I'm actually new to Haskell. I've written this code for Queue, but the last line always face this syntax error .

> ```
> Syntax error in input (unexpected '=').
> ```

I really can't figure out what's wrong :(

```
module Queue where
data Queue a = Q[a] deriving Show

class QDS q a where
  pop :: q a -> (a, q a)
  push :: q a -> a -> q a
  lengthQS :: q a -> Int
  isEmpty :: q a -> Bool

instance QDS Queue a where
  pop (Q (x:xs)) = (x, (Q xs))
  push (Q x) a = (Q (x ++ [a])) 
  lengthQS (Q x) = length x
  isEmpty q = lengthQS q == 0  -- This line fails
```

Comment: Please be sure to tag the language you are using - it is the most important tag.

Comment: Your code compiles with `FlexibleInstances` and `MultiParamTypeClasses`, which, for future reference, is helpful to include when you post code. Is it possible you used a tab instead of spaces somewhere?

Comment: @Eric can you make this into an answer so Negar can accept/close this question?

Comment: @NegarAlinaghi do you really need the type class here? Why not just write the functions directly agains `Queue`?

Comment: You might find this useful too: [Simple and Efficient Purely Functional Queues
and Deques](http://www.usma.edu/eecs/SiteAssets/SitePages/Faculty%20Publication%20Documents/Okasaki/jfp95queue.pdf) :D

Comment: @Carsten König, I want to implement Douglas–Peucker line generalization algorithm with queue structure, thus I decided to write queue as a module and then import it to my algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

### Solution without compiler extensions:

Remove the type parameter `a` in both class and instance:

```
class QDS q where
instance QDS Queue where
```

and it compiles fine *without language extensions*.

### Need for MultiParamTypeClasses

The reason the compiler wants `MultiParamTypeClasses` is obvious: Your `QDS` supplies two type parameter. If you do not include the instance, MultiParamTypeClass is enough.

### Need for FlexibleInstances

Without Flexible instances, a concrete declaration like `instance QDS Queue Int where` compiles fine. You have to ask someone else for a deeper explanation, I can only superficially say `a` is more flexible then `Int`.

### Why is one parameter enough?

You do not place any constraints on your payload `a`. To include it is just as unnecessary as for `Functor`, `Foldable` etc.

### Typeclasses

A word of advice, taken from the comments: With an OOP background, typeclasses give you a false impression of feeling at home. You will rarely need to define a class. The ability to pass functions around is more powerful than using objects (or data constrained to a typeclass for haskell).

Comment: However, requiring the queue to be parametrized over its element type may not be something you want. It's not necessarily so great if you implement unboxed queues.